# Planar system: Analyse the existence of equilibria and determine their bifurcations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

> > Consider the system
> >     $$
> > \dot{x}=x+ay-y^3,\quad \dot{y}=b-2y+x.
> > $$
> >     Analyse the existence of equilibria and determine their bidurcation.

The equilibria can be determined by setting
$$
0=x+ay-y^3,\quad 0=b-2y+x.
$$
This yields $x=2y-b$ and $y^3-(a+2)y+b=0$.

Now, in order to have fold bifurcation that can yield to born equilibria, we need to have simple eigenvalue $\lambda=0$. Hence, I consider the linearization matrix which is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & a-3y^2\\1 & -2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Looking at the char. polynomial and equating it to 0, I get
$$
\mu^2+\mu-2-a+3y^2=0
$$
so that this has simple eigenvalue $0$ iff 
$$
a+2=3y^2.
$$
Hence, I get from the last equilibrium equation from above that
$$
y^3-3y^3+b=0\Leftrightarrow b=2y^3.
$$
Moreover, I get
$$
y=\pm\left(\frac{a+2}{3}\right)^{1/2}
$$
hence $b=\pm 2\left(\frac{a+2}{3}\right)^{3/2}$. So when I draw the $(a,b)$-diagram, i.e. a on the $x$-axis and $b$ on the $y$-axis, I get the bifurcation curve $L$ which looks as

[image]

where the blue line is $b=2\left(\frac{a+2}{3}\right)^{3/2}$ and the red line is $b=-2\left(\frac{a+2}{3}\right)^{3/2}$.

How can I now see where exactly I have how many equilibria? Don't know whether for parameter values $b$ larger or smaller as the values on the bifurcation curve two equiliria are born resp. vanish.

Comment: 1) There is something wrong with coordinates $y_1$ and $y_2$; 2) The method is always almost the same: start from finding equilibria (and do it right), then study when something bad happens with Jacobi matrix associated with these equilibria (bad = Jacobi matrix becomes degenerate or acquires pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues). It's also good to perform nullcline analysis -- it mostly tells you about saddle-node bifurcations, but you can estimate the number of equilibria and the scenarios through which this number can change.

Comment: No. Bifurcation curve (or hypersurface) in parameter space means the set of parameters at which bifurcation happens. It's not "equilibria coordinates in terms of parameters".

Comment: @Evgeny Improved my question.